# Apache Write Permissions Outside WWW Folder

Tags: apache-2.2, permissions

I have the following system (Linux/CentOS):

- user `DEV`
- user `APACHE`

`DEV` is in groups: `APACHE`,`DEV`
`APACHE` is in groups: `APACHE`,`DEV`

The user `APACHE` runs the apache server.

My `WWW` folder is under `/home/dev/www/`
My document folder is under `/home/dev/docs`
In my `WWW` folder there is a symbolic link which points to the doc folder.

My php application needs to create new folders inside the doc foler.
The permissions flags of the doc folder are `rwxr-xr-x`.
And I get permission denied if I try to mkdir to that folder.
If I change the permissions to `rwxrwxr-x` all is fine.
My question: is that correct? Or shall I change the user who run apache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My recommendation would be to keep ownership of the files in `/home/dev/(www|docs)` set to `DEV:DEV` and allow `APACHE` user to write to required folders via a group permission.

This way folders which `APACHE` needs to write to will have permissions set to `rwxrwxr-x`, while folders which it only needs to read from can have permissions set to `rwxr-xr-x`.

There is one extra thing to consider in this scenario. All files/folders created by `APACHE` user will be owned by `APACHE:APACHE` (assuming that the default group for `APACHE` user is `APACHE`). Because of that you may not be able to write to those files/folders with your `DEV` user depending on what `umask` is set for `APACHE` user.

To fix this inconvenience you can set SGID bit on the folder which `APACHE` is going to write to. In your case:

```
chmod g+s /home/dev/docs
```

and set appropriate `umask` for `APACHE` user:

```
umask 0002
```

That way all files/folders in `/home/dev/docs` created by `APACHE` user will have owner set to `APACHE:DEV` and permissions set to `rwxrwxr-x` for folders and `rw-rw-r--` for files.

Please note that while this is an acceptable solution for development environment, on production server you may not want `APACHE` user to have `umask` set to `0002`.

Comment: And what you suggest for production env?

Comment: Well in production environment you won't have a DEV user, will you? :) In any case the safer umask is 0022, with no write permission for group.

Comment: Changing the user running apache is an alternative solutio?

Comment: Changing apache user is not a good solution. While it might work for a single user system, it wouldn't work for a multi user environment where you have more than one dev.

Comment: But the problem is that I create fodlers by using a php script. So, in some way APACHE user, or whoever with the right permissio, must have write access to the doc folder

Comment: My answer explains how to do this. In development environment you will give APACHE user write access via group permissions. On production system APACHE user should be the only one writing to this folder so APACHE can simply own it.